# Using MemoryBarrier for Propagation of Changes in Dictionary<int, T> Multithreaded App

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I have a .NET 3.5 application where a Dictionary instance is shared between two threads. I understand that the Dictionary is not thread-safe in any way by itself but I only have one thread that can ever modify the Dictionary and the other thread just needs to ensure it has the latest values when performing its work. (even *latest* isn't a hard requirement in the strictest sense)

One thread is receiving intermittent serial data and calling a Set function to change the values in the dictionary. (This Dictionary is a fixed size after the initial setup and I'm basically just using it as a sparse array)

The second thread gathers up the values currently stored in the dictionary and does some work with them through GetLatestValues().

```
public class HwMemoryMap{
   Dictionary<int, HwDataItem> HwCache;

   public void Set(HwDataItem dataItem){
       HwCache[dataItem.PtId] = dataItem;
       MemoryBarrier();
   }

   public List<HwDataItem> GetLatestValues(){
       System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();
       List<HwDataItem> HwDataItemList = new List<HwDataItem>();
       // do work here to pull appropriate values out of HwCache
       HwDataItemList.Add(HwCache[0]); // etc
       return HwDataItemList;
   }
}
```

Is the MemoryBarrier() call here enough to ensure that changes to the dictionary Value for a specific Key are propagated across all threads/cores?

My testing hasn't revealed any problems but that doesn't exactly give me any comfort given the nature of these problems.

Comment: I don't think it is. I believe that the setter may actually change the structure of the underlying hash table, which could cause strange behavior if it's interleaved with the get operation.

Comment: Yeah I've seen caution related to operations where the dictionary size changes or key hash values change but in my case only the values ever change after initial setup. If I knew of a first-class 'sparse array' class I'd probably use that instead of dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not safe. You still run the risk of writing and reading from the data structure simultaneously. There is a trick you can use that works pretty well if the writes are infrequent enough. Basically you make sure the data structure referenced by `HwCache` remains immutable. Every time you want to change the data structure you first copy it into a new instance and change the new instance inside an exclusive lock. Then when your changes are done you swap the `HwCache` reference out with the new instance. For this to work correctly you have to mark `HwCache` as `volatile`.

```
public class HwMemoryMap
{
  private object lockobj = new object();
  volatile Dictionary<int, HwDataItem> HwCache;

  public void Set(HwDataItem dataItem)
  {
    lock (lockobj)
    {
      var copy = new Dictionary<int, HWDataItem>(HwCache);
      copy[dataItem.PtId] = dataItem;
      HwCache = copy;
    }
  }

  public List<HwDataItem> GetLatestValues()
  {
    var local = HwCache;
    var HwDataItemList = new List<HwDataItem>();
    // do work here to pull appropriate values out of local
    HwDataItemList.Add(local[0]); // etc
    return HwDataItemList;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not thread-safe. The reader might read from multiple dictionaries. The fix is to copy HwCache to a local first.

Comment: @usr: Yep, awesome catch! Fixed.

Comment: By the way, I inadvertently demonstrated why these tricks are difficult to get right. That little bug [usr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr) spotted could have been disastrous! For those reading this answer look at the edit history to what [usr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr) spotted that I missed.

Comment: I used that pattern before and hit that issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with C#, but I wouldn't make assumptions about what's going on "under the hood".  In particular, if the insert code assume it's the only one accessing the data structure, it may leave partially updated references while it is allocating space or otherwise.

Consider the following (simplified) code:

```
Insert(TKey key, TVal val) {
    if (this.size > this._threshold) {
        // Allocate more space and
        // move to a new table
    }
    // Find location and insert
}
```

If all of that is happening within your one store (and I'm not saying it is, I don't know how C# implements dictionaries), then a memory barrier doesn't save you if any of the intermediate state propagates to a different thread.

What might make more sense is a pair of reader/writer locks.  If the common case is reading, you can have multiple threads all grab the reader lock, and only when you need to make an update do you need to give exclusive access to the writing thread.

Comment: Also, I found this: http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/03/why-dictionary-indexer-is-not-thread.html while searching around the Internet.  Also not saying that it's correct, but he seems to have a better idea about the inner workings of a C# dictionary.

--Edit--
From further reading of his code snippet, it looks like there may be some read-copy-update which would give readers a consistent view.  But that's just speculation...